# How does one segue between children of UIPageViewControllers in a Swift App?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uipageviewcontroller

How does one segue and pass data between children of UIPageViewControllers programatically. This must be done because I use items such as: TableViewCell clicks and Toolbar Item Buttons.

My UIPageViewController is set up as follows:

```
//
//  RootViewController.swift
//  slide
//
//  Created by Justin Zollars on 2/12/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 rmb. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

let didFinishUploadPresentNewPage = "com.snapAPI.presentNewPage"

class RootViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var navViewController : UINavigationController!
    var oneViewController : oneViewController!
    var districtsViewController: DistrictsTableViewController!
    var currentViewController:UIViewController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSLog("*****************************")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "navigateHome", name: didFinishUploadPresentNewPage, object: nil)
        // set UIPageViewControllerDataSource
        self.dataSource = self

        // Reference all of the view controllers on the storyboard
        self.navViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navViewController") as? CustomNavigation
        self.navViewController.title = "One"
        // println("homeTableViewController has landed!")

        self.oneViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("oneViewController") as? oneViewController
        self.oneViewController.title = "Three"

        self.districtsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("districtsViewController") as? DistrictsTableViewController
        self.districtsViewController.title = "Two"
        // println("Camera has landed!")
        self.currentViewController = self.navViewController
        // Set starting view controllers
        var startingViewControllers : NSArray = [self.oneViewController]
        self.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        // println("Hey swab. C'mere. Listen up.")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        switch viewController.title! {
        case "Three":
            return navViewController
        case "One":
            return districtsViewController
        case "Two":
            return nil
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    //  order: Two(districtsViewController) |One (navViewController) |camera (oneViewController)

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        switch viewController.title! {
        case "One":
            return oneViewController
        case "Three":
            return nil
        case "Two":
            return navViewController
        default:
            return nil

        }
    }

    func navigateHome() {
        var navigateToHome : NSArray = [self.navViewController]
        self.setViewControllers(navigateToHome, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

**I even have a solution which sucks, I'm looking for the right way to do this.**

I use a combination of Notifications and Singletons, which feels like an Ugly hack.

```
import Foundation

class DataToAPI {

    var hood: NSString!

    class var sharedInstance :DataToAPI {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = DataToAPI()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }
}
```

I use the singleton in other controllers to share data like this:

```
var sharedInstance = DataToAPI.sharedInstance
```

and if you were reading the code above, I have a notication which calls `navigateHome()`

**What is the right way to Segue (or acomplish its equivalent) using UIPageViewControllers?**